# How to keep searched words in search bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have search bar in app. The scenario is that I search "Tree" in first time running the app. In the second time, I search "orange" and "apple" in third time.

In Fourth time, I just type "T" and then "Tree" keyword will appear in search result table.

I want to keep my search keywords.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In short you should store all the searched words somewhere like:

-`UserDeafults`

-`CoreData`

-`LocalFile`

-`Server`

and than check if stored word contains let query and display if its true

Comment: thanks bro. Do you have any reference videos or code?

Comment: @MayPhyu I have a sample code where I'm getting suggestions from server, but thats the case where the server part is already implemented
do you need it ?

Comment: sure bro. I want to view your code if possible  bro.

Comment: @MayPhyu you can try these links : https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift , http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/tableview-search-in-swift , https://grokswift.com/swift-tableview-search-bar/

Comment: @MayPhyu this link for tutorial is much better

Comment: The example site is added Search bar table view controller. My project is I have view controller and add "Search" uibarbutton item. The example is searching the item in it defined array. My problem is that.. I would like to keep the user searched keywords. User might type "abcde" keyword (for eg.) which will be display as "not found" msg. But, when user type "ab" again, his previous typed "abcde" keyword will appear in drop down list.

Comment: @MayPhyu so as I typed in the answer you should choose the storage, and store all the searches for a specific user,
like when the user typing "abcde"  and hitting enter you save this "abcde" to database for example and than next time this database will be your predefined array